# Netlogo, using ticks as onset of events and and how to make turtles eat other turtles

Tags: netlogo

this is my first post on the community. I have a set of turtles that start at a color-defined region and when I press "go" they move to another color-defined region filled with other breeds. My questions are: How can I set them to move ONLY after a certain amount of ticks has passed? How to make certain breed sprout only after certain amount of ticks has passed? How to make an specific breed of turtles to eat another breed and be satisfied after "x" number of meals? Thanks (It would be a plus if you could make the eaten turtles to dissapear when eaten).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. These are all good questions, but the format here is that you're expected to ask one question at a time, show the code you have written so far, and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding number of ticks:**

`ticks` is a reporter that tells you how many ticks have there been, you can think of it as a global variable.

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/ticks.html

**Regarding `turtle` eating another kind of turtle. YUM!:**

You can use [in-cone](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/in-cone.html) to check if there's a `breed` agent in front of a turtle, if so then choose `one-of` them and `ask` that one to `die`, finally increment a `hungriness` variable in a random or constant value. The turtle is only going to look for food when that `hungriness` is below a certain value.

There is a lot of info in the [NetLogo dicitonary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/)!